# PHP-FPM sockets temporary unavailable in NGINX under high-load even if nginx hits static file

Tags: php, wordpress, sockets, caching, nginx

I setup a docker container (alpine) with the following configuration:

- Nginx
- PHP7
- PHPFPM
- Wordpress with WP-Super-Cache

Nginx was configured (or so I believe) to serve the static html pages generated by wp-super-cache.

Most connections in the docker container are done through unix sockets (mysql db in wp, phpfpm in nginx).

**Problem:**
The initial and consequent request to the site are really fast but when I stress-test the server I get strange php-fpm errors:

```
*144 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unav
ailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.102, server: www.local.dev, request: "GET /hello-world/ HTTP
/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "www.local.dev"
```

My question is why php-fpm is used if nginx takes care of serving those files under high-stress situations and even if php-fpm is used why the unix socket fails.

And of course any tips for solving this?

*I discovered that if I let the stress tester tool run for a long time php-fpm is creating new processes to take care of the load, but I'm looking to push on a aws ec2 micro.t2 instance and I don't think it can support all the processes that it spawn on my 8 core machine.*

**Configuration:**

Nginx:
https://gist.github.com/taosx/c1ffc7294b5ca64d11a6607d36d5b49e

I have tried switching the php-fpm unix socket with the TCP/IP (127.0.0.1:9000) but I still get the same error and initial request get slower by 20%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I had the wrong path for my wp-super-cache generated html files.
Instead of `/wp-content/cache/supercache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html` I had `/wp-content/cache/$http_host/$cache_uri/index.html`.
Note the missing supercache subfolder.